# How to help this org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So, I started running the basic opening chrome on web, selenium program.

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

public class Testt {

```
static {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./driver/chromedriver.exe");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.close();

}
```

}

Getting below errors:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}) on port 50054
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jun 08, 2022 11:17:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Jun 08, 2022 11:17:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 102, so returning the closest version found: 101
Jun 08, 2022 11:17:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 102 of 101
Jun 08, 2022 11:17:58 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:345)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:376)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should give a try for this argument added for chrome options:

```
.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use This code in it....

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked like a charm. Why chrome options are getting complicated with updated versions?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the *incompatibility* between the version of the `binaries` you are using as follows:

You have downloaded and used `chromedriver=102.0` which got initiated successfully.
But your are still using `chrome=101`

Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v102*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/102.0.5005.61/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

- Supports Chrome version 102

**Solution**

Solution
Ensure that:

***Chrome Browser is updated to current chrome=102***

Answer (score 0):

Instead of driver.close(); use driver().quit(); while closing the browser and it should resolve