# WARNING: Connection reset java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, testng-annotation-test

```
Apr 04, 2023 7:43:38 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I am getting all my results as expected. but after all output completes then I am getting this type of error.

Comment: Check this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540689/how-to-help-this-org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-websocketlistener-onerror

Comment: Also please look over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question!

Comment: @Shawn to be honest the answers in that question are dubious at best (barring the last one, which may not be relevant). @ OP we need a lot more information than just a posted error. See the "how to ask" link above.

Answer (score 0):

That error isn't really an error, it's just a warning. What it means is that a socket/server socket disconnected or something happened to the connection.