# Unable to find and add data into the respective columns with dyanamic data table using Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, dynamic-data-display, uisearchtextfield

`User will search an element from the search text box, provide quantity against the element searched and click on Add button to get the data added to the table just below the selection inputs. User is allowed to add multiple records and once she/he is done with adding elements, there are certain lists from where user needs to select the appropriate records, add comments and finally click Submit button to save the data.
First Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXNjI.png)
Second Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4c9i.png)
Third Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDXt.png)
Forth Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYX8f.png)
I am sharing DOM for empty table details below:
Fifth Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oJ9m.png)
Sixth Screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3eFJ.png)

```
//Search Medicine, Define Quantity and Add
WebElement medicine_search = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txt_medicine']"));
medicine_search.sendKeys("DOLO 250MG SYRUP-60ML");
WebElement define_quantity =
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txt_quantity']"));
define_quantity.sendKeys("20");
WebElement btn_add =
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btn_addprescriptions']"));
btn_add.click();
```

Add button click does not add data to the table below and I am stuck at this point in my script.

Answer (score 0):

tip: add logs or print message after click or sendkeys It will help to trace the issue

1. **Check Add button Xpath**

`WebElement btn_add = driver.findElement(By.xpath**("//input[@id='btn_addprescriptions']"))**; **btn_add.click();`
Add button is above the table **

**Only If your sendKeys are not working  search medicine**

2.**Press Enter**

`medicine_search.sendKeys("DOLO 250MG SYRUP-60ML");`
**medicine_search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);**

Comment: Hey Rakshasa, tried the way you have suggested, added few assertions to check the code is getting executed. However the button Add click is still not adding details to the dynamic table just below it. There is also an error in console. I am sharing the same for your reference.

Comment: Oct 09, 2023 12:34:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:401) at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:434)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:256)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540689/how-to-help-this-org-openqa-selenium-remote-http-websocketlistener-onerror   pls check the link

Comment: or use clickbutton